# Binding a DataGridComboBoxColumn to s static Source

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagridcomboboxcolumn

I have a `DataGrid` with a `DataGridComboBoxColumn` and I want to bind it to a static source containing only options "A","B","C"

current xaml:

```
<DataGridComboBoxColumn x:Name="ControlOption" Header ="ControlOption" Width="100"
    SelectedValueBinding="{Binding Operation}"
    SelectedItemBinding="{Binding Choices}"
    ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True"
    ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
    IsReadOnly="True"
    CanUserResize="True">

    <DataGridComboBoxColumn.ElementStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ComboBox">
            <Setter Property="ItemsSource" Value="{Binding Choices}" />
        </Style>
    </DataGridComboBoxColumn.ElementStyle>
    <DataGridComboBoxColumn.EditingElementStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ComboBox">
            <Setter Property="ItemsSource" Value="{Binding Choices}" />
        </Style>
    </DataGridComboBoxColumn.EditingElementStyle>
    <DataGridComboBoxColumn.ItemsSource>
        <col:ArrayList>
            <sys:String>AVS</sys:String>
            <sys:String>DB</sys:String>
            <sys:String>AVS_DB</sys:String>
        </col:ArrayList>
    </DataGridComboBoxColumn.ItemsSource>

</DataGridComboBoxColumn>
```

Please let me know how the codebehind would look like: to implement the `DataGridComboBox` currently I am using the codebehind as:

```
_ds = new DataSet();
DataTable table = new DataTable();
_ds.Tables.Add(table);
DataColumn c1 = new DataColumn("IsActive", typeof(bool));
table.Columns.Add(c1);
DataColumn c2 = new DataColumn("DataGridTextBox_QCList1", typeof(string));
table.Columns.Add(c2);
DataColumn c3 = new DataColumn("DataGridTextBox_QCSummary", typeof(string));
table.Columns.Add(c3);
DataColumn c4 = new DataColumn("Choices", typeof(string));
table.Columns.Add(c4);
datagrid.ItemsSource = _ds.Tables[0].DefaultView;
```

What changes do I need to make to make the necessary impact in populating the datagridcombobox (the basic problem is, I am not even seeing a dropdown)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use a `DataTable` as the `ItemsSource` there is no way for the `DataGrid` to know that only a limited amount of values is possible for a given column, hence it will only generate `DataGridTextColumns` for the string columns.

You can hook the event [`AutoGeneratingColumn`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagrid.autogeneratingcolumn.aspx), check via the event args if the column of interest is being generated, and change the `Column` in the event args to a `DataGridComboBoxColumn` with the respective binding and `ItemsSource` set.

Comment: I could then bind the DataGridComboBox Column separately to a static source?